# How to lock highstocks range selector to specific time range

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to lock the navigator range selector to 24h? 
We want to be able moving on the only with 24h window on our timeline without the option to enlarge it, and be able only to reduce it. 
the whole time window can be bigger than 24h.

in this example: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping
we can see the light blue navigator, we can enlarge it and change the selected range, in our case we want to lock it only to 24h and to be able only move it on the timeline.

Comment: To prevent the range to be not too small you can set minRange http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.minRange There is no option like 'maxRange', so you need to set that behaviour on your own. You can use axis' setExtremes event to set the desired extremes - the example of it can be found on Highcharts forum https://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=21741